# What joins in SQL do I need to get the Category name based on the ID from a different table?

Tags: php, sql, database, model-view-controller

I am trying to work out the inner joins or the type of join I need in SQL for me to get the Category name based on the ID of a product from a different table.

I'm making a PHP product page script using my own MVC framework and right now I'm able to get all the data easily for my product but I need to get the category name based on the cat_id. I'm unsure how to do this kind of query as I have never actually had to use them before.

I have two tables, the items table that has lots of data and the important one in this question is 'cat_id':

```
id      name         ###cat_id###
-----------------------------
1      item name         2
2      item name         1
3      item name         3
```

and the second database is the category table that looks like this:

```
###id###      name         status
-----------------------------
1      catty            1
2      cat              0
3      cat              1
```

So what I want to happen is say item 1 has cat_id = 1 it echos Catty as the category on the views bit but i cant figure out how to do the joins.

Here is my PHP code in the views:

```
                <?php if($data['isProducts']) { foreach($data['products'] as $product) : ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                        <div class="card h-100 shadow-1 rounded-0">
                            <a href="<?php echo FULL_ROOT;?>/item/<?php echo $product['id']; ?>/">
                                <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="<?php echo FULL_ROOT;?>/uploads/items/<?php echo $product['id']; ?>/<?php echo $product['preview_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>">
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <a href="<?php echo FULL_ROOT;?>/item/<?php echo $product['id']; ?>/"><h2 class="card-title font-weight-bold f-18"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h2></a>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-light btn-lightb float-left mr-1"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Live Preview" href="<?php echo $product['demo']; ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-light btn-lightb float-left"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-white">
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light float-left btn-lightb">
                                      <!-- get name from cat table based on id -->  <?php echo $product['cat_id']; ?>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light float-right btn-lightb">
                                        <?php echo $data['settings']['payment_currency_sym'].$product['price']; ?>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; } else { ?>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-primary shadow-1 rounded-0" role="alert">
                            <b><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> No Items Available!</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function profile($user_id = '')
{
    // Get data from model
    $sdata = $this->setting->getAll();
    // Check if empty
    if($user_id == '') { redirect(''); }
    // Get data from model
    $udata = $this->user->getUserByUsername($user_id);
    $pdata = $this->user->getUserProducts($udata['id']); //Get the cat name based on id from this bit
    if(is_array($pdata[0]) ) {
        $isProducts = true;
    } else {
        $isProducts = false;
    }
    $data = array(
       "user" => $udata,
       "products" => $pdata,
       "isProducts" => $isProducts,
       "settings" => $sdata
    );
    // Checks if no data found (404)
    if($udata == false) { redirect('error'); }
    // Load view
    $this->view('marketplace/user/profile', $data);     
}
```

Here is my model code:

```
public function getUserProducts($user_id)
{
   // $bind = [':username' => $user_id];
    $sql = "select ??????????? from msi_items INNER JOIN/OUTER JOIN ?????";
    $results = $this->run($sql);
    //$results = $this->db->select('msi_items','status = 1 AND author_id = :username', $bind);
    if(!is_array($results[0])) {
        $new_results = array();
        array_push($new_results, $results);
        return $new_results;
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not given any of the joins which you try to understand. Probably, you want to have a look at a SQL tutorial? The whole stuff around view and controller should be irrelevant - try to build the proper query first, some tool like the MySQL shell or phpMyAdmin will help you model it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
select i.cat_id, c.name
from items i inner join category c on i.cat_id = c.id
```

Or, like the below if you want to have all items even if there are no categories. In this case you will get nulls in where there are no c.names

```
select i.cat_id, c.name
from items i left join category c on i.cat_id = c.id
```

Comment: Would this work? SELECT * FROM msi_items
INNER JOIN msi_itemscat
ON msi_items.cat_id= msi_itemscat.id
WHERE msi_items.status = 1 AND msi_items.author_id = :username @p4n1 and also how do i then echo that other database data in the view?

Comment: It depends on what you are after. This would give you back the records from msi_items, where there is a category name, for a certain status and a certain author. If you also need the category name, try adding it to your select

Comment: what i'm trying to do is get all the columns/rows from the items table and then get the category name from the category table based on the 'cat_id' in the items table which equals the 'id' in the category table.

Comment: How about:SELECT msi_items.*, msi_itemscat.name FROM msi_items INNER JOIN msi_itemscat ON msi_items.cat_id= msi_itemscat.id WHERE msi_items.status = 1 AND msi_items.author_id = :username

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks very much and then for the php echo i should do a msi_itemscat.name AS catname? One question what does the msi_items.* do? why the full stop

Comment: That is if you want the catname alias to be called then by your php. Please don't forget to upvote if that was helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks very much and as you seem really to understand what you are talking about.. im building a badge/achievement system but a dynamic one from the database. But basically as they are dynamic its much more difficult to actually show the data for only users that have unlocked it so im using a foreach currently which gets all the achievements but there is no way of only showing the achievements if unlocked Here is a preview: https://ibb.co/f7SuKd

Comment: So basically here is a picture of my database: https://ibb.co/cGHTed and this is how i get the badges:     public function getUserBadges()
    {
        $results = $this->db->select('msi_badges','status = 1');
        if(!is_array($results[0])) {
            $new_results = array();
            array_push($new_results, $results);
            return $new_results;
        } else {
            return $results;
        }
    } so would i do another sql join thing to say if in the user table moderator = 1 then show the moderator badge as right now it just shows them all!